# Did Ezra Bridger's eyes change color?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In *Star Wars: Rebels* we meet a character named Ezra Bridger. At first his eye color appeared to be an unnatural purple color.

[image]

**Other viewers** have also noticed and commented on his purple eyes:

> In terms of the appearance of the character the **lavender/purple eyes** and the blueish/black hair are curious choices
>   -[RebelsReport.com](http://rebelsreport.com/2014/02/24/a-closer-look-at-the-six-heroes-of-star-wars-rebels/) .

and

> Kanan looked into Ezra's **electric purple eyes** and smiled.
>   -[source](https://www.wattpad.com/174641160-star-wars-rebels-ezra%27s-force-journal-continues)

There's no doubt - his eyes definitely started out purple. *However* the character's main image on [his Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ezra_Bridger) shows his eyes now looking more blue-ish and the same page now claims his eye color is blue.

[image]

Did they change his eye color from purple to blue? If so, Why?

Comment: I'm honestly not seeing any difference!

Comment: @The Doc whoa I'm looking at it on my phone and you're right, they look the same. I'll have find some better pictures to show the difference. I'll clarify my question tomorrow.

Comment: @TheDoc I edited my question by narrowing it down so that it's much clearer what I'm asking. I also added better sources and images.

Comment: I can see quite a distinct difference now; much better 

Comment: Some humans actually do have [purple eyes](http://primary.slate.com/content/slate/blogs/browbeat/2011/03/25/elizabeth_taylor_beautiful_mutant.html)

Answer (score 5):

Wookieepedia is not necessarily an infallible source - the image in question appears to come from a guide book which may not have used "official" or production assets from the show but had secondary illustrations.

StarWars.com would be better - here is a gallery of stills from episodes. The color does appear to be different than just a basic blue

http://www.starwars.com/ezra-bridger-biography-gallery